# Mixing a base map with a layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to load a base map (streets) and have a feature layer from the arcGIS online system.  I can view the base map, but I am receiving a few errors when i try to combine the base map and feature layer.

Here is my code...

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS DevLabs: JavaScript Starter App</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.esri-feature {
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.55rem;
  font-feature-settings: "liga"1, "calt"0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/esri/css/main.css">
 <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/"></script>
<script>
require([
  "esri/WebMap",
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/widgets/Search",
  "esri/widgets/Feature",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (WebMap, Map, FeatureLayer, MapView, Search, Feature) {


  const fLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    portalItem: {
      id: "52a26407bcb244ac9a29acf64aab4d0b"
    }
  });

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets",
    layers: [fLayer]
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-77.0487, 38.8935],
    zoom: 18
  });

  var search = new Search({
    enableButtonMode: true,
    enableLabel: false,
    enableInfoWindow: true,
    showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
    view: view
  });
  view.ui.add(search, "top-right"); // Add to the map

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

What am i missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your portal item is a web map. If you use the portal item 1fbe63d7741643ee86f798d84f7ee299 (the feature collection you're using in the web map), it works. However, you have to zoom out a little. It won't show with zoom > 14

https://jsbin.com/pipayir/edit?html,output